# Container wrapping around tallest child in CSS Grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, word-wrap

I think I might be having the wrong approach with this design problem. Here is a codepen with a reproduction of the issue and a Stack Snippet :

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/inthemoodfornow/pen/VwmjRVB)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-container {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 1000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "img description" "share share";
  grid-template-columns: 271px 1fr;
}

.img-meta {
  grid-area: img;
  width: 272px;
  align-self: center;
  position: relative;
}

.red {
  width: 272px;
  height: 380px;
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  align-self: center;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 272px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="img-meta">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Problem is immediately apparent: the blue container is out of the parent grid container. The green container contains text and expands depending on the quantity of said text, which is what is wanted. The red container has fixed dimensions and contains an image which needs to position itself at the center of the green container at all times. **Blue container needs to be just under the red container regardless of position of red container.**

When the text is longer than the img-meta container, design is as expected.
But when the text is shorter than img-meta, the design appears as shown in the snippet: because the blue container is relatively positioned, it escapes the flow of the document and the grey grid container doesn't wrap around it.

I understand this is normal behaviour for a relatively positioned container, but I am out of ideas to get the expected design.
I have tried to design this with flexboxes initially, before picking a grid.
I tried to use `min-height` on the text container to force it to always have the height of the of the img-meta container but no luck because it will create a lot of empty space at the top.
I have also tried to have the blue container out of its parent and remove its positioning in order to get the grid to wrap around it, but this will leave a space between the red and the blue container!

Maybe the grid direction is wrong for that type of design, and I'm looking forward to see your ideas!

Comment: Do you need the position: absolute on the blue element?

Comment: @VojislavSibinovic as I said in my question, absolute positioning was an attempt to get that blue element to always follow the position of the red element, which centers itself depending on the height of the green element!

Comment: The code in your Stack Snippet does not match the code in your CodePen.

Comment: @TylerH is that important? The codepen merely contains an extra comment for something I tried earlier. The problem is the same anyway! But I'm happy to change it if it needs to match?

Comment: the height of the blue container is known?

Comment: @TemaniAfif it can be! But it doesn't have to be. I gave it a specific height here so that it shows on the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @JoannyRouviere Typically you want your demos across platforms to be consistent in every way. In this case it's important because the layout is completely different in one case vs the other, and your question is about layout.

Comment: @TylerH noted! I will make sure it matches in the future. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

```
.blue { 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.grey {
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure we are trying to achieve the same thing; I've just tried it on my Codepen and it doesn't work as expected. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/inthemoodfornow/pen/NWbRXjx)